# Why Entity Framework Core is showing async methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up a simple Web API on C# using Entity Framework Core.

I tried to program a `get()` function but Entity Framework Core shows me `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Why is this happening?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOYWf.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: You likely don't have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: ideally, when working with databases, you should be using Async because, your app will be blocked while it waits for the query to finish. you should really look up Async programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstOrDefault is part of a different namespace than FirstOrDefaultAsync.

FirstOrDefaultAsync belongs to the Entity Framework Core package. FirstOrDefault belongs to Linq.

to get the FirstOrDefault method add this using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

read these for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault is a linq query  and it is used when dealing with a non asynchronous method  while FirstOrDefaultAsync is used while using asynchronous method.
example where each of them where used
you can as well make your method asynchronous in other to consume FirstOrDefaultAsync()